# Angular ui-router ui-sref including *all* parameters, not just desired ones

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got a paginated view in an Angular 1.5 app using ui-router, which takes a large number of search parameters.

Records in this view have `ui-sref` links on them that allow the user to filter their search by a specific parameter, like `category`.

These links work great- almost. The problem is that the links they generate include not only the `category` parameter I specify, but also all the other parameters currently in use for that view: `page`, et cetera, et cetera.

For example:

**current URL:** `/index/?page=8&query=querytext`

**Link `ui-sref`:** `ui-sref="index({category: record.category})"`

**desired link URL:** `/index/?category=desiredCategory`

**link URL it actually creates:** `/index/?page=8&query=querytext&category=desiredCategory`

The resulting URL is not just not the desired one, because it includes the page parameter it might even link to a page that doesn't even exist. Obviously, I could specify empty parameters for each and every kind of parameter this view could take, but given the number this would quickly get clunky.

Is there any way to get ui-router to create `ui-sref` links that direct only to the parameters specified, instead of that parameter and all other parameters currently in use? I've tried specifying defaults in my ui-router state but that doesn't seem to work:

```
.state('index', {
    url: "/?page&query&category",
    params: {
        page: {
            value: '1',
            squash: true
        },
        query: {
            value: '',
            squash: true
        },
        category: {
            value: '',
            squash: true
        },
    },
    templateUrl: "index.html",
    controller: 'PostController'
})
```

Any insights into how to deal with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the answer:** To disable ui-sref from inheriting all the current view parameters, you have to add a second directive to the link: `ui-sref-opts="{inherit: false}"`.